# Wi-Fi required for downloading apps larger than 19 MB

Tags: 8.1, store, lumia-520

Why is my Lumia 520 asking for Wi-Fi in order to install apps larger than 19 MB? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have an unlimited data plan?

Comment: Tether to another phone if you have one. The original phone will think it is on wifi and the phone providing the data link won't care.

Comment: It is not compulsion that you have to download only through wifi. It only suggests you that you can download faster if you have a wifi network compared to mobile networks. >100Mb file also can be downloaded through mobile data if you have enough balance

Comment: @NiranthReddy can you describe how >100mb apps can be downloaded on mobile data?? is there any setting?? because i can not see any apps >100 mb is downloaded on my phone via mobile network.

Comment: @Nirav No setting changes are required as per my knowledge. I just tried installing >900MB game in my phone through mobile data and it started to download.

Answer (score 1):

### Change Data Sense Settings

Data Sense helps you save data by controlling access to your data plan. Either you or your cellular provider tells Data Sense about your data plan. If you have a limited data plan (like 100 MB - 20 GB/month) Data Sense will limit data plan usage, meaning it'll ask apps like Store to use Wi-Fi for large downloads.

To fix this you can change your Data Sense settings

1. Open **Settings**.
2. Search for **Data Sense**.
3. Change allowance it to *Unlimited*.

When Data Sense thinks you're on an unlimited data plan it wont ask apps to use Wi-Fi instead of the cellular connection.